# How to set custom cookies using Firefox Add-on SDK (using Services from Firefox Add-on SDK)

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on creating a Firefox Add-on SDK extension that would set custom cookies (two cookies with `name` and `value` attributes) on Firefox v41, with **jpm**.

Essentially, if I open the add-on's [Panel()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) and click on set, the cookie values should be set. On refresh, I should be able to see them on my developer console, in which ever tab I open. And, on reset, they should be removed.

I tried modifying the code snippet from the Add-ons [Code snippets ->
Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Cookies) on Mozilla's developer website:

```
Services.cookies.add("http://www.google.com/", "/", "test", "value");
```

The issue I am facing is with the Services module. When I run my extension in debug mode, it throws `ReferenceError` saying that `Services` is not defined.

I am unable to find another way of setting the cookies permanently. Using `document.cookie` would set the cookie values for the panel only and that is not what I am looking for.

I also tried the Chrome way of doing it when I read somewhere that Firefox's Add-on framework is compatible with the Cookie API of Google Chrome.

Please let me know if you need more information on the issue I am facing.

Comment: *"it throws ReferenceError saying that Services is not defined."* - what is the next logical step when something is missing? Keep in mind that the page you're looking at is called *"Code snippets > Cookies"* not *"Complete and Selfcontained Examples, batteries included > Cookies"*

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I wasn't able to find a Services module to clear the ReferenceError. Any help would be appreciated..
The import at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm) location doesn't work either..

Comment: *"The import at this location doesn't work either"* - what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Within the Firefox Add-on SDK, you can gain access to [`Services`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm) using the following:

```
var { Services }  = require("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

However, your use of [`Services.cookies.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager2#add()) is erroneous in that you are not passing enough arguments to the method. Here is something that works:

```
var { Services }  = require("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
let is_secure = false;
let is_http_only = false;
let is_session = false;
let expiry_date = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000 + 3600*24); //Time in seconds 1 day from now.
Services.cookies.add(".host.example.com", "/cookie-path", "cookie_name", "cookie_value",
                     is_secure, is_http_only, is_session, expiry_date);
```

This will result in a cookie that looks like:

[image: Example cookie panel]

In order to use some methods of [Services.cookies (nsICookieManager2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager2) you will also need to require [Chrome Authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority).  For instance, to enumerate through the cookies you could do:

```
var { Cc, Cu, Ci} = require("chrome");
let cookieEnumerator = Services.cookies.getCookiesFromHost("google.com");
while (cookieEnumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
  let cookie = cookieEnumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsICookie2); 
  console.log(cookie.host + ";" + cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value + "\n");
}
```